# how to redirect to 404 error instead of 403 when user enter wrong subdirectory in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am using nginx as my webserver and what I want is to redirect user to 404 error instead of 403 when user enter a wrong subdirectory,how can I do this .below is my nginx server section conf :

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                               
    listen 80;                                                                                                                                                                     
    index index.html;                                                                                                                                                              
    server_name localhost;
    location / {                                                                                                                                                                   
            #add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;                                                                                                                           
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;                                                                                                                               
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;                                                                                                                             
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                           
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                                                                                                                      
            proxy_pass  http://10.10.66.66:8080;
    }                                                                                                                                                                              
    error_page 404 /404.html;                                                                                                                                                     
        location = /40x.html {                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;                                                                                                                                          
        location = /50x.html {                                                                                                                                                     
    }
```

}

Comment: 403 usually has precedence. It means "I'm not telling you whether this resource exists or not, but if it did exist, then you wouldn't be allowed to access it". That works well with whitelisting where you specify which resources are legal to see, and which ones are not. Turning it into 404 means "you would be allowed to access it, but it doesn't exist". If the client used the wrong resource (say spelled wrong), this makes it a lot harder to find the problem. You should have a very good reason to report incorrect status codes.

Comment: You configuration sends every request to `http://10.10.66.66:8080` and returns whatever that server returns. Your `error_page` statements will be ignored.